# xforms repeat element with a picture upload?

Tags: upload, repeat, xforms, media-type

Could someone please show me how to code up, using XForms, a widget that allows one to choose a picture file for upload, repeatedly if necessary?  That is, the user uploads one pic at a time, but has the option to continue uploading again and again if necessary.

It could either be the  element or just a simple  element.  I am not sure how the repeat element is related to the trigger element.  Is it that the repeat element tells the XForms processor which UI elements to display repeatedly?  And the trigger element is a button that updates the underlying model?

I am unclear on how to capture this information. Do I need something roughly like:

```
<xforms:repeat 
                <xforms:trigger>
                    <xforms:label>Add pic</xforms:label>
                    <xforms:upload
                        ref="data/picture[@id='1']"
                        mediatype="image/*">
                    </xforms:upload>
                </xforms:trigger>
</xforms:repeat>
```

If a user uploads 5 pics, for example, would it be possible to identify each picture as pic1, pic2, pic3?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Xforms Repeat element repeats across existing data to display, what you want to do is display existing photos and *insert* new ones. The XForms wikibook its quite comprehensive, so you might want to look at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/Insert and http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/Repeat_into_table

Below is an *untested* example, that should give you a good indication of what you need to do.

```
<html 
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
   xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" 
   xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
   <head>
      <title>XForms insert example</title>
      <xf:model>
         <xf:instance>
            <Data xmlns="">
               <Photo name="My Photo">
                    <!-- Data here -->
               </Photo>
               <NewPhoto name="">
               </NewPhoto>
            </Data>
         </xf:instance>
      </xf:model>
   </head>
   <body>
      <fieldset>
         <legend>Company Phone List</legend>
         <p>
            <b>Uploaded Photos...</b>
            <ul>
            <xf:repeat id="list" nodeset="/Data/Photo">
               <li><xf:output ref="@name" /></li>
            </xf:repeat>
            </ul>
         </p>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
         <legend>Add New Photo</legend>
         <p> <!-- here is where we get the new record -->
            <xf:input ref="/Data/NewPhoto/@name">
               <xf:label>Photo Name:</xf:label>
            </xf:input>
            <xforms:upload
                        ref="/Data/NewPhoto"
                        mediatype="image/*">
            </xforms:upload>
            <xf:trigger>
               <xf:label>Insert... </xf:label>
               <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
                  <xf:insert nodeset="/Data/Photo" at="index('list')" position="after" />
                  <xf:setvalue ref="/Data/Photo[index('list')]/@name" value="/Data/NewPhoto/@name" />
                  <xf:setvalue ref="/Data/Photo[index('list')]" value="/Data/NewPhoto" />
               </xf:action>
            </xf:trigger>
         </p>
      </fieldset>
   </body>
</html>
```